# Phaser. Moving game character on 2d grid, along fixed path

Tags: javascript, 2d, phaser-framework

Started working with Phaser making my first game and so far progress has been fine, but I have hit a snag, where my inexperience is getting the best of me.

So the situation is as follows. I have a map generated from a 2D matrix. The Purple tiles in the picture.

```
var testMap = [
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],];
```

And I have a range of tiles around the player, that he can move to. The Green tiles in the picture.

I've also made a system that reads the mouse location and generates a path to the tile that the mouse is over. I have this path information in an array. The White tiles in the picture.

```
var path = [[3,3],[4,3],[5,3],[5,4],[5,5]];
```

And now I want to make the player move along this path, by using the coordinates of the path array. And ideally have a function in between, that checks if the player has stepped on a trap when he steps on a new tile while moving.

But I keep hitting a wall with this function. Any and all ideas would be a appreciated.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Not completely related comment: try phaser isometric plugin for your isometric game.

Comment: @PooyaEstakhri already am using that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/tweens/interpolation) example. It's about tween interpolations, but illustrates a tween along a path as well. Basically instead of a single value for x, you pass an array.